# How to support Servlet 3.1 with WebSphere 8.5.5 Traditional

Tags: servlets, websphere, websphere-8

As per WebSphere 8.5.5 traditional spec, WebSphere 8.5.5 is using servlet version 3.0. Is there any way to twick Websphere 8.5.5 to use servlet version 3.1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

WebSphere 8.5.5.x supports only Servlet 3.0 API. You can upgrade to v9, which supports 3.1 or even better migrate to WebSphere Liberty, which supports all (3.0, 3.1 and also latest 4.0) and is more lightweight, container friendly runtime.